# Predicting a nonzero mass for the photon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance

This is a concern I had after I had read the reply for a previous question I had: [On the masslessness of the photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755062/on-the-masslessness-of-the-photon/755066#755066)

So, I have been told that there are cases in which the gauge symmetry that preserves the masslessness of the photon breaks. Under what circumstances does that happen? And when it does, is the mass acquired by the photon consistent with the experimental evidence discussed in [On the masslessness of the photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755062/on-the-masslessness-of-the-photon/755066#755066) ? And finally, is the symmetry breaking spontaneous or not?

Thanks

Comment: It would have been better to wait for a day or two to see if different/better answers to your original question were posted before posting yet another (hard to distinguish) question.  I'd also suggest that accepting an answer so quickly (to your earlier question) is not a good idea as it discourages people from bothering to post additional answers.

Comment: Okay, I hear you @StephenG-HelpUkraine. It was suggested to me in the other post to break my questions into two and to accept the answer, as it was indeed replying to the parts of the question that are not included here. I will be more patient in the future. Thanks:)

Comment: see related question and answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/why-cant-photons-have-a-mass

Comment: "is the symmetry breaking spontaneous or not?". Spontaneous, of course. In superconductive media, there is a precise, verified mass.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive. Thank you so much @CosmasZachos.

Comment: [WP source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect#Paradigm_for_the_Higgs_mechanism).  [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430375/rest-frame-of-massive-photon-in-meissner-ochsenfeld-effect).

Comment: Gauge symmetry cannot be spontaneously broken, see [Elitzur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%27s_theorem)